# Synaptics touchpad tap-to-click is not working in Ubuntu 15.10(Gnome)

Tags: gnome, touchpad, synaptics, 15.10, tap-to-click

I upgraded my ubuntu gnome installation to 15.10 and everything is kinda good except for the touchpad single-tap functionality. **Single-tap-to-click is not working**. And I have tried all possible solutions like editing `synaptics.conf` file.

One thing that I noticed is the following, which is kinda strange. For every input device the schema has an original and `deprecated` entry but for `touchpad` it just has `deprecated`. Is this the cause?

I don't know how to resolve this issue. Please help!

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard.deprecated:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse.deprecated:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.smartcard 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.trackball.deprecated:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.wacom:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.wacom.eraser:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.wacom.stylus:/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.wacom.tablet-button:/
```

Below is the screenshot of my mouse&touchpad settings:
[image]

Also, my `synclient` results are like,

```
$ synclient | grep TapButton

TapButton1   = 0  
TapButton2   = 0  
TapButton3   = 0
```

my `xinput` command yields the following,

```
$ xinput list
Virtual core pointer              id=2  [master pointer  (3)]  
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
 ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad        id=12  [slave  pointer  (2)]  
 ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir)    id=13  [slave  pointer  (2)]  
Virtual core keyboard             id=3  [master keyboard (2)]  
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard    id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]  
 ↳ Power Button                   id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]  
 ↳ Video Bus                      id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]  
 ↳ Power Button                   id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]  
 ↳ Sleep Button                   id=9  [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Results of `xinput list-props 12` command:

[image: Xinput list-props result]

Comment: Answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87642/no-touchpad-settings) suggest that your touchpad may be recognised as a mouse. Some of the solutions listed could help

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I updated the question with 'xinput' output. Please see!

Comment: Did you try any of the approaches in the link? xinput has obviously identified the touchpad, but gnome hasn't, so the synaptics drivers are probably functioning incorrectly or are not linked

Comment: I tried all of the fixes but nothing works for me  :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput list-props 12` terminal command.

Comment: Why post a picture? You could post it as text. And it is not full.

Comment: It's way too huge text to type. I have a couple of device IDs left but it won't be relevant

Comment: You can copy the text from a terminal using `Ctrl` + `c`.  It makes it easier to read your question on mobile devices. And please post the whole output; if it's very long, post in a [gist](gist.github.com) and link to it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found a fix to solve my problem:

I added the following line to my `bashrc` so that it can compile every time I log in.

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

Although not a pretty hack, but it works fine. Hope the community fixes the bug..

---

*Update:*   This hack seems to work fine in Ubuntu 17.04 also, which means the bug isn't fixed yet by the community.

**P.S.** Also see [this great solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/851657/292500)

Comment: since you have found a working setting it is better way is to override synaptics touchpad configuration at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` as outlined [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Frequently_used_options)

Comment: Brilliant, this worked Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 39):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

it worked for me...

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work after a reboot. is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: @kmario23 at a guess, you'll need to set synaptics driver module options. Unfortunately I'm on mobile and can't easily confirm that or look up how to do it, but hopefully that gives an idea where to start.

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me make it persistent: http://askubuntu.com/a/772094

Answer (score 11):

Have you updated the mouse settings? After updating I had the same issue, but it was just that tap to click had been disabled.

[image: mouse and touchpad settings]

Otherwise, according to [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-settings/+bug/1489730) it could be worth logging out and back in.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't see those three options[tap to click,  two finger scroll, natural scrolling]  under touchpad. But scrolling and everything works fine but tap-to-click does not

Comment: can you please tell me the procedure to update the settings?

Comment: move your mouse to the top right, click on the settings button, go to mouse & touchpad , settings should be there

Comment: I don't see that option there. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and solved it with similar technique mentioned in [Eliah Kagan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/243137) which was adapted from [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201198/touchpad-stops-working-after-login#comment250411_201198) but with some differences:

1. Launch "**dconf Editor**" app. (if not installed, run: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`)
2. Go to:  ***org→gnome→desktop→peripherals→touchpad***
3. Enable ***tap-to-click***.

Comment: works like a charm!!

Comment: I met a similar problem after installing 18.04. It seems that since my mouse was connected during install, the system saw touchpad as a mouse also. Editing the wanted settings with this method and rebooting without my mouse connected fixed it.

Comment: not work in gnome shell 41

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, after I upgraded to ubuntu GNOME wily werewolf. so I make custom shortcut in keyboard for getting back functionality of touchpad, just fill `synclient TapButton1=1` on command also fill the name form then choose your favorite keyboard combinations. it's fine enough for a while and wait for update.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, a few days ago and face the same issues. This does the trick:

```
    sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

It only needs to download this stuff, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings window allows users to setup the mouse.
But I need to configure the touchpad.
The console helps to first reboot or sleep "synclient tapbutton1 = 1"

As I understand it, the system incorrectly identifies the device,It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it worked for me on UbuntuGnome 15.10 so i made an entry in startup applications.

Using your favorite editor, create a script with the following contents and save it as e.g. `touchpad.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 4

# Below width 1 finger touch, above width simulate 2 finger touch. - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 8

# vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling - values: 0=disable 1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 1

# vertical, horizontal, corner - values: 0=disable  1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 0 0 0

# stabilize 2 finger actions - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Jumpy Cursor Threshold" 250

# pad corners rt rb lt lb tap fingers 1 2 3 (can't simulate more then 2 tap fingers AFAIK) - values: 0=disable 1=left 2=middle 3=right etc. (in FF 8=back 9=forward)
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 0 0 0 0 1 2 3   

exit
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x touchpad.sh
```

Now run the script and see if it works.

Original Information found here: http://www.mepis.org/docs/en/index.php?title=Configuring_the_touchpad_with_xinput

Comment: thanks! But if i do that, tap to click works but scrolling doesn't. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As an end user, the easiest way I found is to change to " Primary button" right click in mouse touchpad settings.

Double tap still works as primary left, tap in the button area works as right tap.

Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script to automate this process. It will be automatically started when the system starts. So, you don't have to run the same command again and again. The link of the script is [github.com/Ryko-git/click-on-touchpad](https://github.com/Ryko-git/click-on-touchpad) .

The installation process is very easy. It is given on the github page.