# Touchpad won't scroll after suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, touchpad, 23.04

Hey just installed a fresh Ubuntu install (on a dell Inspiron 7415 2-in-1), everything works fine except the touchpad. The touchpad only seems to work fine after I fully restart my laptop, but after close the lid (suspend) the touchpad loses gestures and also randomly clicks by itself.

I saw some other posts this may be useful (xinput list):

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:15                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:15                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:15                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:15                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

dmesg of suspend:

```
[  489.154154] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  490.459603] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  490.465606] Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds
[  490.466352] Freezing user space processes
[  490.468519] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
[  490.468524] OOM killer disabled.
[  490.468524] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
[  490.469822] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
[  490.469824] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  490.488118] atkbd serio0: Disabling IRQ1 wakeup source to avoid platform firmware bug
[  490.602298] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  490.769623] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  490.800281] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[  490.800288] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
[  490.801524] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
[  490.801529] [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F41FC00000
[  490.801548] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
[  490.801840] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
[  490.802665] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
[  490.807915] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
[  490.807954] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
[  490.808187] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[  490.808189] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_low uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[  490.808190] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_high uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[  490.808191] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[  490.808192] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[  490.808193] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[  490.808194] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[  490.808195] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[  490.808196] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[  490.808197] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[  490.808198] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[  490.808199] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[  490.808200] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[  490.808200] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[  490.808201] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[  490.808202] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[  490.808203] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[  490.961459] nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[  491.115192] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  491.115212] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  491.950041] OOM killer enabled.
[  491.950044] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  491.953701] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[  491.964634] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[  492.016464] PM: suspend exit
[  492.032412] audit: type=1107 audit(1695749517.303:71): pid=605 uid=100 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.23" mask="receive" pid=2295 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=663 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=100 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  493.228734] usb 3-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  495.621861] wlp2s0: authenticate with 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57
[  495.636786] wlp2s0: send auth to 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57 (try 1/3)
[  495.691369] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  495.692385] wlp2s0: associate with 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57 (try 1/3)
[  495.695673] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[  495.714534] wlp2s0: associated
[  495.767741] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by 04:4e:5a:94:c6:57
[  495.819135] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: I have the same issue, on xwayland as well. I saw [an old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87642/no-touchpad-settings) that implies the touchpad is being recognised as a mouse. I could be wrong here but running out of ideas as well.